# How to transfer json strings back and forth between HTML and PHP via jQuery Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Hi I'm new to PHP and jQuery and I was doing some tests trying to figure out how things work. But I keep having trouble transferring data back and forth between my web page and the php file on the server. Here is the code:

```html
<center>
  <form>
    <hr>
    <table style="width:80%;border:3px;">
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="name" placeholder="First Last"></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="ssn" placeholder="First Last"></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="birth" placeholder="First Last"></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" id="xxxx" placeholder="First Last"></td>
        <td align="center"><button type="button" id="add">Add</button></td>
        <script>
          $("#add").click(function() {
            var nameIn = $('#name').val();
            var ssnIn = $('#ssn').val();
            var birthIn = $('#birth').val();
            var xxxxIn = $('#xxxx').val();
            
            xxxxIn = "\$" + xxxxIn;
            $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:"database_update.php",
              dataType:"JSON",
              data: {
                name: nameIn,
                ssn: ssnIn,
                birth: birthIn,
                xxxx: xxxxIn
                },
              success: function(ret) {
                var out = JSON.stringify(ret);
                alert(out);
                }
            });
          });
        </script>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</center>
```

```php
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$ssn = $_POST['ssn'];
$birth = $_POST['birth'];
$xxxx = $_POST['xxxx'];

header('Content-type: application/json');
if (isset($name))
{
  $ret = array(
    "name" => $name,
    "ssn" => $ssn,
    "birth" => $birth,
    "xxxx" => $xxxx
    );
  echo json_encode($ret);
} ?>
```

The alert function was never triggered and the response from php was successful.

Comment: Do you really have a space between your tag an php?  "<? php".  If so, that may cause you some problems.

Comment: yes....but after deleting that space it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your <head> tag?  And is your database_update.php in the same directory as your HTML file?

Comment: Yes I did and there was data transferring back from the server but the if statement was gone...seeing from the network tab of Chrome. And yes all files are in the "public_html" directory

Comment: I copied your code and tried it on my server and it's working fine.  If you click on the item in the Network tab, what does it give in the "Response" or "Preview" tab?  Is there any other code in database_update.php ?

Comment: OK now it has a json string from "Response" along with the PHP code but I still can't trigger the alert() function. And there's just another "include" statement including another php file with just information about mysql. (like user name and password, etc).

Comment: OK.  The Response should not have any PHP code included.  To reduce complexity, remove the include statement (or comment it out).  Then try.  If everything works, there is a problem with the included file.  Perhaps another "<? php" ?

Comment: Yes it worked! Turns out it IS the redundant whitespace that caused all the problems...Thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome!  I posted an answer with a recap of the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it seems a little unlikely that anyone will stumble across this post with the exact same issue, I'll post an answer with the essence of the comments.

1) Remove white space from PHP tags "`<?php`", not "`<? php`"

2) Include jQuery in your  tag (you already had this done)

3) Make sure files are in the same directory, or include the directory path in your AJAX call (you were fine here, too)

4) Verify the Response in the Network tab of the Chrome Console or Firebug.  No PHP should ever be visible here.

5) Reduce complexity as much as possible.  Once it is working, gradually add code back in.